# Error with specifying colClasses in read.csv

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a dataset called "rating.csv". The dataset look like this :

`rating: 2.97, 3, 3, 3.41, 3.5, 3.5, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3.67`

I am trying to specify colClasses in read.csv to speed up the reading of csv file. First I create the colClasses like this :

```
classes <- c("double")
```

Then I read the dataset with

```
data <- read.csv('rating.csv', colClasses=classes,
  comment.char="", na.strings='NULL')
```

But I get an error with this read.csv

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, 
 nlines, na.strings,  : scan() expected 'a real', got '"3.67"'
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with this code ? Or is there another way to change type of the dataset colclass besides in `read.csv`?

Comment: I think we need to see the dataset itself.  Can you post a link to it?

Comment: Error seems to indicate that the last column is character, not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I think that means that your data is in string format instead of numeric/double/whatever options are available in csv format.